# HIgher Dimensional Search Trees With Non-Boolean Operators

Tags: c++, data-structures, tree, binary-search-tree

Recently I have been working on an idea of mine. My thought process goes that binary search trees are so effective because comparison operators are themselves binary. So, if I were to overload a comparison operator to return 0-3, a search tree with four children would be more efficient.

To explain, say I overloaded a basic integer class's comparison operators to return 0 if a is <50% smaller than b, 1 if a is <=100% smaller than b, 2 if a is >50% larger than b, 3 if a is >100% larger than b
I'm assuming this has been done before but I can't find any information about it as I have no idea what it's called.

Any insight would be helpful. I have a BST set up and just started implementing the 'N-Tree' (N being the possible return values of the comparison operator) but, frankly, it's getting quite convoluted and I would rather read about this than code it (I'm lazy, I know...).

Thank you!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree

Answer (score 0):

This is a perfectly reasonable idea to pursue. If you have the ability to classify nodes as "near" or "far" in addition to maintaining a direction, you can potentially build much flatter trees that are much faster at getting from one node to another.

There are some other data structures that use similar ideas. For example, the [BK-tree](http://blog.notdot.net/2007/4/Damn-Cool-Algorithms-Part-1-BK-Trees) uses edit distance to categorize strings into different buckets based on their discrete distance, and more general [metric trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_tree) are based on related ideas.

There's another fundamentally different way to do this that's the basis for B-trees, and that's to put multiple keys into a single node and then have children for "less than the first key," "between the first and second key," etc. You'll probably find a lot of good ideas if you check out that space.

Some challenges you'll need to address: keeping trees balanced is hard - that's why red/black trees, AVL trees, splay trees, etc. are so important. They're all based on the idea of doing tree rotations to keep things balanced, and tree rotations work because they change the balance of the nodes in the tree without breaking the tree invariants. You'll need to work out a new way to balance the tree shape you're proposing, which in all likelihood will be harder than the basic tree mechanics. Consider looking into the [scapegoat tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scapegoat_tree)'s approach of ripping out large imbalanced chunks of a tree and optimally rebuilding.